# Firefox 46 keeps crashing on xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, firefox

Every time when i open firefox it keeps working fine and after a couple of minutes it crashes. I have gstreamer and flash installed so I am not sure what is causing this. Here are the error details:

```
Add-ons: ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.2,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:46.0,%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D:2.7.3,firefox%40getpocket.com:1.0,loop%40mozilla.org:1.2.6,e10srollout%40mozilla.org:1.0,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:46.0,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:46.0
BuildID: 20160425115337
CrashTime: 1463486067
EMCheckCompatibility: true
EventLoopNestingLevel: 1
FramePoisonBase: 00000000f0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1462613582
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 -- 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 362
StartupTime: 1463485713
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86","buildId":"20160425115337","version":"46.0","vendor":"Mozilla","platformVersion":"46.0","xpcomAbi":"x86-gcc3","hotfixVersion":"20160106.01"},"partner":{"distributionId":"canonical","distributionVersion":"1.0","partnerId":null,"distributor":null,"distributorChannel":null,"partnerNames":[]},"system":{"memoryMB":3950,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":2,"cores":2,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":58,"stepping":9,"l2cacheKB":256,"l3cacheKB":2048,"speedMHz":1800,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3","hasSSE4_1","hasSSE4_2"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"3.16.0-71-generic","locale":"en-US"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"adapters":[{"description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2","vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center","deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"3.0 Mesa 10.3.2","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"basic"}}},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":false,"e10sCohort":"unsupportedChannel","telemetryEnabled":false,"isInOptoutSample":false,"locale":"en-US","update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":true},"userPrefs":{"browser.cache.disk.capacity":358400,"browser.newtabpage.enabled":false,"browser.newtabpage.enhanced":false,"browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser":true,"browser.startup.page":3,"browser.urlbar.suggest.searches":true,"browser.urlbar.userMadeSearchSuggestionsChoice":true,"privacy.donottrackheader.enabled":true},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":true,"defaultSearchEngine":"google","defaultSearchEngineData":{"name":"Google","loadPath":"[distribution]/searchplugins/locale/en-US/google.xml","submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"}},"profile":{"creationDate":16928},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"firefox@getpocket.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"When you find something you want to view later, put it in Pocket.","name":"Pocket","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":16916},"loop@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Web sharing for Firefox","name":"Firefox Hello","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.2.6","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":16916},"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Staged rollout of Firefox multi-process feature.","name":"Multi-process staged rollout","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":16916},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ubuntu modifications for Firefox","name":"Ubuntu Modifications","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"3.2","scope":8,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16696,"updateDay":16696,"signedState":2},"{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ads were yesterday!","name":"Adblock Plus","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"2.7.3","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16928,"updateDay":16928,"signedState":2}},"theme":{"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","blocklisted":false,"description":"The default theme.","name":"Default","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"46.0","scope":4,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":16916},"activePlugins":[{"name":"Java(TM) Plug-in 11.91.2","version":"11.91.2","description":"Next Generation Java Plug-in 11.91.2 for Mozilla browsers","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":true,"mimeTypes":["application/x-java-vm","application/x-java-applet","application/x-java-bean","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.5","application/x-java-bean;version=1.5","application/x-java-applet;version=1.6","application/x-java-bean;version=1.6","application/x-java-applet;version=1.7","application/x-java-bean;version=1.7","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.8.0_91","application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.8.0_91","application/x-java-applet;version=1.8","application/x-java-bean;version=1.8","application/x-java-applet;deploy=11.91.2","application/x-java-applet;javafx=8.0.91","application/x-java-vm-npruntime"],"updateDay":16928},{"name":"Shockwave Flash","version":"11.2.202.621","description":"Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":false,"mimeTypes":["application/x-shockwave-flash","application/futuresplash"],"updateDay":16934}],"activeGMPlugins":{"gmp-gmpopenh264":{"version":"1.5.3","userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}},"activeExperiment":{},"persona":null}}
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoqMpJC0tZY
UptimeTS: 354.3171797
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 46.0
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that doing a purge of vlc media player has resolved this.

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
```